# Ordering algorithm which returns search items in Amazon

Tags: algorithm, search-engine, ranking, sorting

I was wondering how an algorithm might work when you input the search for an item in Amazon. I'm guessing that the more popular seller might have a higher rank, and maybe the more the number of products sold, the higher the rank. But is that it? Surely when a user from a different country types the same query, different results will be observed right? What are the factors that influence such a ranking? What technique or algorithm is used in the implementation of ranking?

Thanks!

Comment: While I think a question about what factors *should* be taken into account by a search engine might be useful, it seems to me that asking specifically about Amazon's search engine makes it nearly unanswerable (I doubt Amazon publishes it), and sort of a trivia question -- a great deal might depend as much on other infrastructure at Amazon (and how its organized) as the algorithm itself. Just for example, the search algorithm itself might not take countries into account, but the input to it might well be based on whether items are available in a particular place.

Comment: Just to clarify. You are not asking about the `suggested items`. :) Btw, perhaps you should add tag `ranking` or so.

Comment: @JerryCoffin yeah it doesn't have to be amazon's results, but im specifically interested in ecommerce websites. any popular algorithms?

Comment: Most search engines don't publish their exact algorithms, both because it's a large part of their value, and because they generally need to protect against SEO (i.e., manipulation of results).

Comment: @OckhamsRazor - They could be using a system similar to Google's [PageRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagerank) algorithm, which uses a host of mostly unknown (to us) factors to determine the importance of results in search results.

Comment: A weighted 2x2 matrix (different weighs for different inputs?? sex, country, likes hi-fi audio, likes -handbags -watches). _If someone knows another approach to ranking, scoring, at least I would be interested. There are statistical approaches, nerual network approaches which I think could do the same thing. Perhaps they are not effecient and therefore not in use in this area? Or are they?_.

Comment: @OlofEdler - Markov chains, link analysis, click-tracking (how many people choose to go to one product over others in a search result), neural networks with backpropagation could all be used by Amazon - they have thousands (nay, tens of thousands) of machines at their disposal to crunch the billions of data points they have a day to update their search results and rankings.

Comment: @birryree - I bet Amazon could be employing 500 mathematicians (the very number would make a very interesting useless fact).

Comment: A9 is the search engine behind amazon.com. You might find some interesting info on their homepage http://a9.com/-/company/productsearch.jsp